# package name not showing in AndroidMennifest.xml in react native project

Tags: javascript, react-native

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<!-- OPTIONAL PERMISSIONS, REMOVE WHATEVER YOU DO NOT NEED -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<!-- These require runtime permissions on M -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<!-- END OPTIONAL PERMISSIONS -->

<queries>

<!-- Support checking for http(s) links via the Linking API -->

<intent>

<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

<data android:scheme="https"/>

</intent>

</queries>

<application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="false" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="YOUR-APP-URL-HERE"/>

<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="YOUR-APP-SDK-VERSION-HERE"/>

<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:exported="true">

<intent-filter>

<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

</intent-filter>

</activity>

<activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" android:exported="false"/>

</application>

</manifest>

i have found everywhere but i couldn't found the solution.plzz help me,because of this problem i cant connect my app to firebase

Comment: Please format your code and see [mre]

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in **android > app > build.gradle**

[image]